# Show ads in hard code instead of dinamically from theme option

Tags: php, wordpress

I'am Using a wordpress theme that extract the ads from the admin panel, I want instead of that to inject manually my ad codes there :

Here is my index page code:

```html
<?php get_header(); // add header  ?>
<?php
    // Options from admin panel
    global $smof_data;

    // Hide Date format
    $dateformathide = (isset($smof_data['dateformathide'])) ? $smof_data['dateformathide'] : '0'; 
    // Date format
    $dateformat = (isset($smof_data['dateformat'])) ? $smof_data['dateformat'] : 'M j, Y';

    if (empty($smof_data['banner_p1'])) { $smof_data['banner_p1'] = ''; }
    if (empty($smof_data['banner_p2'])) { $smof_data['banner_p2'] = ''; }
    if (empty($smof_data['banner_p3'])) { $smof_data['banner_p3'] = ''; }
    if (empty($smof_data['banner_p3'])) { $smof_data['banner_p4'] = ''; }
    if (empty($smof_data['banner_p3'])) { $smof_data['banner_p5'] = ''; }    
    $home_pag_select = (isset($smof_data['home_pag_select'])) ? $smof_data['home_pag_select'] : 'Infinite Scroll';
    $display_ads = (isset($smof_data['display_ads'])) ? $smof_data['display_ads'] : 'Yes';
?>

<!-- Begin Home Full width -->
<div class="home-fullwidth">
    <!-- Begin Sidebar (left) -->
    <?php get_template_part('sidebar2'); ?>
    <!-- end #sidebar (left) --> 

    <!-- Begin Main Wrap Content -->
    <div class="wrap-content">


        <?php if (is_category()) { ?> 
            <div class="archive-header"><h3><?php esc_html_e( 'All posts in:', 'anthemes' ); ?> <strong><?php single_cat_title(''); ?></strong></h3><?php echo category_description(); ?></div>
        <?php } elseif (is_tag()) { ?>
            <div class="archive-header"><h3><?php esc_html_e( 'All posts tagged in:', 'anthemes' ); ?> <strong><?php single_tag_title(''); ?></strong></h3></div>
        <?php } elseif (is_search()) { ?>
            <div class="archive-header"><h3><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Search Results for: %s', 'anthemes' ), '<strong>' . get_search_query() . '</strong>' ); ?></h3></div>
        <?php } elseif (is_author()) { ?> 
                <div class="archive-header"><h3><?php esc_html_e( 'All posts by:', 'anthemes' ); ?> <strong><?php the_author(); ?></strong></h3></div>
        <?php } elseif (is_404()) { ?> 
            <div class="archive-header"><h3><?php esc_html_e('Error 404 - Not Found', 'anthemes'); ?> <br /> <?php esc_html_e('Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn\'t here.', 'anthemes'); ?></h3></div>
        <?php } ?> 


        <ul id="infinite-articles" class="masonry_list js-masonry"> 
        <?php $num=0; if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); $num++; ?>

        <?php if ($display_ads == 'Yes') { ?>
   <?php if (!empty($smof_data['banner_300_1'])) { ?>
                <?php if ($num==$smof_data['banner_p1']) { echo '<li class="homeadv">'. stripslashes($smof_data['banner_300_1']) .' <span> '. esc_html__('Advertisement', 'anthemes') .'</span></li>';} ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if (!empty($smof_data['banner_300_2'])) { ?>
                <?php if ($num==$smof_data['banner_p2']) { echo '<li class="homeadv">'. stripslashes($smof_data['banner_300_2']) .' <span> '. esc_html__('Advertisement', 'anthemes') .'</span></li>';} ?>
            <?php } ?>    
            <?php if (!empty($smof_data['banner_300_3'])) { ?>
                <?php if ($num==$smof_data['banner_p3']) { echo '<li class="homeadv">'. stripslashes($smof_data['banner_300_3']) .' <span> '. esc_html__('Advertisement', 'anthemes') .'</span></li>';} ?>
            <?php } ?>      
            <?php if (!empty($smof_data['banner_300_4'])) { ?>
                <?php if ($num==$smof_data['banner_p4']) { echo '<li class="homeadv">'. stripslashes($smof_data['banner_300_4']) .' <span> '. esc_html__('Advertisement', 'anthemes') .'</span></li>';} ?>
            <?php } ?>   
            <?php if (!empty($smof_data['banner_300_5'])) { ?>
                <?php if ($num==$smof_data['banner_p5']) { echo '<li class="homeadv">'. stripslashes($smof_data['banner_300_5']) .' <span> '. esc_html__('Advertisement', 'anthemes') .'</span></li>';} ?>
            <?php } ?> 
        <?php } else { ?>
            <?php if (!empty($smof_data['banner_300_1'])) { ?>
                <?php if ($num==$smof_data['banner_p1']) { echo '<li class="ex34 homeadv">'. stripslashes($smof_data['banner_300_1']) .' <span> '. esc_html__('Advertisement', 'anthemes') .'</span></li>';} ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if (!empty($smof_data['banner_300_2'])) { ?>
                <?php if ($num==$smof_data['banner_p2']) { echo '<li class="ex34 homeadv">'. stripslashes($smof_data['banner_300_2']) .' <span> '. esc_html__('Advertisement', 'anthemes') .'</span></li>';} ?>
            <?php } ?>    
            <?php if (!empty($smof_data['banner_300_3'])) { ?>
                <?php if ($num==$smof_data['banner_p3']) { echo '<li class="ex34 homeadv">'. stripslashes($smof_data['banner_300_3']) .' <span> '. esc_html__('Advertisement', 'anthemes') .'</span></li>';} ?>
            <?php } ?>      
            <?php if (!empty($smof_data['banner_300_4'])) { ?>
                <?php if ($num==$smof_data['banner_p4']) { echo '<li class="ex34 homeadv">'. stripslashes($smof_data['banner_300_4']) .' <span> '. esc_html__('Advertisement', 'anthemes') .'</span></li>';} ?>
            <?php } ?>   
            <?php if (!empty($smof_data['banner_300_5'])) { ?>
                <?php if ($num==$smof_data['banner_p5']) { echo '<li class="ex34 homeadv">'. stripslashes($smof_data['banner_300_5']) .' <span> '. esc_html__('Advertisement', 'anthemes') .'</span></li>';} ?>
            <?php } ?> 
        <?php } ?> 
            
            <li <?php post_class('ex34') ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

 
            <?php if ( function_exists( 'rwmb_meta' ) ) {  
            // If Meta Box plugin is activate ?>
                <?php
                $youtubecode = rwmb_meta('anthemes_youtube', true );
                $vimeocode = rwmb_meta('anthemes_vimeo', true );
                $hidevideo = rwmb_meta('anthemes_hidevideo', true );
                $soundcloud = rwmb_meta('anthemes_soundcloud', true );
                ?> 

                <?php if(!empty($soundcloud)) { ?>
                    <!-- #### Soundcloud #### -->
                    <?php echo stripslashes_deep($soundcloud); ?>
                    <div class="margin-home-iframe"><?php get_template_part('/functions/custom/social-home-iframes'); ?></div>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php if(!empty($hidevideo)) { } else { ?>
                    <?php if(!empty($youtubecode)) { ?>
                        <!-- #### Youtube video #### -->
                        <iframe class="single_iframe" width="100%" height="180" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo esc_html($youtubecode); ?>?wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        <?php get_template_part('/functions/custom/social-home-iframes'); ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php if(!empty($hidevideo)) { } else { ?>
                    <?php if(!empty($vimeocode)) { ?>
                        <!-- #### Vimeo video #### -->
                        <iframe class="single_iframe" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/<?php echo esc_html($vimeocode); ?>?portrait=0" width="100%" height="180" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen></iframe>
                        <?php get_template_part('/functions/custom/social-home-iframes'); ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php } ?>

                <?php if(!empty($youtubecode) || !empty($vimeocode) || !empty($soundcloud)) { ?>
                <?php } elseif ( has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                    <?php get_template_part('/functions/custom/social-home-images'); ?>
                 <?php } ?>

                <?php if($hidevideo) { ?>
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                    <?php get_template_part('/functions/custom/social-home-images'); ?>
                <?php } } ?>

            <?php } else { ?> 

                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
                    <?php get_template_part('/functions/custom/social-home-images'); ?>
                <?php } ?>

            <?php } ?>


                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="small-content">
                  <div class="an-widget-title">
                    <h2 class="article-title entry-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                      <?php if(function_exists('taqyeem_get_score')) { ?>
                        <?php taqyeem_get_score(); ?>
                      <?php } ?>                    
                    <span class="vcard author"><span class="fn"><?php esc_html_e('Written by', 'anthemes'); ?> <?php the_author_posts_link(); ?></span></span>
                  </div> 
                  <p><?php echo anthemes_excerpt(strip_tags(strip_shortcodes(get_the_excerpt())), 100); ?></p>
                </div><!-- end .small-content -->

                <div class="home-meta">
                    <div class="an-display-time updated"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 
                        <?php if ($dateformathide == '0') { ?>
                            <?php echo time_ago_anthemes(); ?> <?php esc_html_e('ago', 'anthemes'); ?>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <?php the_time(''. $smof_data["dateformat"] .''); ?>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="an-display-view"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i> <?php echo getPostViews_anthemes(get_the_ID()); ?></div>      
                        <div class="home-data">
                            <?php if (function_exists('thumbs_rating_getlink')) { echo thumbs_rating_getlink(); } ?>
                        </div><!-- end .home-data -->                        
                    <div class="clear"></div> 
                </div><!-- Meta ( time and comments ) -->  

            </li>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
        </ul><!-- end .masonry_list -->

         <!-- Pagination -->
        <?php if ($home_pag_select == 'Infinite Scroll') { ?>
            <div id="nav-below" class="pagination" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_posts_link('&lsaquo; ' . esc_html__('Newer Entries', 'anthemes') . ''); ?></div>
                    <div class="nav-next"><?php next_posts_link('' . esc_html__('Older Entries', 'anthemes') . ' &rsaquo;'); ?></div>
            </div>
        <?php } else { // Infinite Scroll ?>
            <div class="clear"></div>
            <?php if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) { ?>
            <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
            <?php } else { ?>
            <div class="defaultpag">
                <div class="sright"><?php next_posts_link('' . esc_html__('Older Entries', 'anthemes') . ' &rsaquo;'); ?></div>
                <div class="sleft"><?php previous_posts_link('&lsaquo; ' . esc_html__('Newer Entries', 'anthemes') . ''); ?></div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } // Default Pagination ?>
        <!-- pagination -->

    </div><!-- end .wrap-content -->
 
<div class="clear"></div>
</div><!-- end .home-fullwidth -->
<?php get_footer(); // add footer  ?>
```

I need to be able to inject manually the code between two DIV .

Thank you

Comment: That is a very WET theme. Holy smokes!

Comment: This is not a code writing service. What have YOU done to try and accomplish this?

Comment: These are funny...`<?php if(!empty($hidevideo)) { } else { ?>`, why not just use `empty($hidevideo)` then? ....I like this theme for it's comical stylings...

Comment: Yes I understand : "This is not a code writing service" i just wanted help .

Comment: These are funny... : yes the theme is pretty wired

Answer (score 0):

So in stead of the block `<?php if ($display_ads == 'Yes') { ?>` you echo out your own code (wrapped in `<li>` tags).

Comment: Thank you but after this condition of Display Ads there is the placement it doent work, can you say to me what do you mean for echo my ad ? can you show me a code please